# Accounting for currency depreciation

Tags: investing

Suppose you have the opportunity to make an investment of X amount of money and you are certain that this investment will return a larger amount of money in Y amount of time.

Is there a law of financing positing that if your profit is below a certain threshold that you will be no better off than if you did not invest in the first place because of the depreciation of the value of the currency? If so, what is this called and how can it be calculated?

Comment: In addition to D Stanley's great answer about inflation, note that if you invest in a currency other than your own, the currency you invest in *becomes part of the investment*. If you live in Canada and buy US Stocks, part of what you are investing in is the USD itself - if the USD strengthens, your stock is worth more in CAD, even if the company itself stays at the same USD.

Comment: As others has pointed out what you are after is D Stanley’s answer. Though you might also be interested in looking up Opportunity Cost. If you consider investment A that returns Y and investment B that returns Z, then the difference will be your opportunity cost. If you could have a higher return on a different investment, you are missing out (missing an opportunity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - it's called the [*rate of inflation*](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/inflation.asp). The rate of return over the rate of inflation is called the [*real* rate of return](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/realrateofreturn.asp).

So if a currency experiences a 2% rate of inflation, and your investment makes a 3% rate of return, your *real* rate of return is only 1%.

One problem is that inflation is always backwards-looking, while investment returns are always forward-looking. There are ways to calculate an expected rate of inflation from foreign exchange futures and other market instruments, though.

That said, when *comparing* investments, typically all investments are in the same currency, so the effect of inflation is the same, and inflation makes  no difference in a comparative analysis.  When comparing investments in different currencies, *then* the rate of inflation may become important.